# Call an Inherited Operation in a Sequence Diagram using the Obeo Uml-Designer Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, uml, sequence, designer, operation

My employer recently adopted the Obeo Uml-Designer plugin for Eclipse as the new UML diagram tool.

I'm having some trouble with Sequence diagrams.  When you call an Operation on an existing class a dialog comes up that lets you select the operation.  Unfortunately it only contains those that are owned by the object directly, and not inherited operations.  I created a class diagram previously and added a reference to the parent class but that doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: What does the tool's customer support at http://www.obeodesigner.com/support say? What do the forums and "_advanced documentation (best practices, FAQ, case-studies, etc)_" at http://www.obeonetwork.com/group/obeo-designer say? BTW: your question does not include [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/416

I will try to fix it for the next 5.0.0 version which will be available at the end of this month.

Thanks for your feedback,
Mélanie

Comment: Thanks Melanie! That is good to know.  I will try version 5 once it comes out.